# Laravel and yajrabox Datatables server side proccessing

Tags: php, datatables, laravel-5.1

I'm working on a project which uses Laravel 5.1 as the server side framework, I built a tables to show leads using jQuery Datatables plugin and  yajrabox Datatables add-on for Laravel.

I am implementing a server side processing but I need to manipulate the data before send it to the client, for do this I need to first pull all the data i'd like to show (to manipulate it) which make the process really long.
this is the code i'm using:

```
public function index()
{ 
   return view('leads.test')->with($data);
}
```

returns the view, and:

```
 public function getLeads()
{
    $end = new \MongoDate(Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->setTimezone(Client::getTimezone(5))->timestamp);
    $start = new \MongoDate(Carbon::now()->subWeek()->startOfDay()->setTimezone(Client::getTimezone(5))->timestamp);
    return \Datatables::of(collect($this->setLeadData(Lead::where('deleted',0)->where('client_id','5')->whereBetween('created_at',[$start,$end])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get())))->make(true);
}
```

return the leads, and last one, the manipulation process:

```
private function setLeadData($leads)
{
    $rtn = [];
    $row = [];
    foreach ($leads as $lead) {
        $row['DT_RowId'] = $lead->_id;
        if(\Auth::user()->canDeleteLeads()){
            $row['checkbox'] = "<input type='checkbox' class='bulk-delete-leads-checkbox' name='bulk_delete_leads[]' id='".$lead->_id."' /><label for='".$lead->_id."'></label>";
        }
        if(Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lead->created_at)->isSameDay(Carbon::now()->startOfDay())){
            $row['date'] = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> at ".Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lead->created_at)->timezone(Client::getTimezone())->format("H:i");
        }else{
            $row['date'] = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> ".Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lead->created_at)->timezone(Client::getTimezone())->toDateTimeString();
        }
        if(is_array($lead->ga_details) && count($lead->ga_details) > 1){
            $row['user_type'] = $lead->ga_details['user_type'];
            $row['device_category'] = $lead->ga_details['device_category'];
            $row['source'] = $lead->ga_details['source'];
            $row['campaign'] = $lead->ga_details['campaign'];
            $row['ad_group'] = $lead->ga_details['ad_group'];
            $row['path'] = $lead->ga_details['path'];
        }
        $row['last_feed'] = null;
        if ($lead->feeds && count($lead->feeds)) {
            $row['last_feed'] = array_reverse($lead->feeds)[0]['message'];
        }
        $row['status'] = $this->setLeadStatusElement($lead->status,$lead->_id);
        $row['owner'] = $this->setLeadOwnerElement($lead->owner,$lead->_id);
        $data['has_reminder'] = false;
        $icon = '';
        $reminder = Notification::where('lead_id', $lead->_id)
            ->where('type', 'lead_reminder')
            ->where('due_time','<=',Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
            ->where('active',1)
            ->where('deleted',0)
            ->first();
        if($reminder){
            $data['has_reminder'] = true;
            $icon = " <i class='fa fa-bell'></i> ";
        }
        $row['full_name'] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-white single-lead-trigger" style="width:100%!important" data-toggle="modal" data-lead-id="' .$lead->_id. '" data-target="#single_lead">No Name'.$icon.'</button>';
        if(isset($lead->the_lead) && count($lead->the_lead)){
            foreach($lead->the_lead as $k => $lead_detail){
                if($k == "full_name"){
                    $row['full_name'] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-w-m btn-white single-lead-trigger" style="width:100%!important" data-toggle="modal" data-lead-id="' .$lead->_id. '" data-target="#single_lead">' .$lead_detail.$icon.'</button>';
                }else{
                    $row[$k] = $lead_detail;
                }
            }
            if(isset($lead->the_lead['full_name']) && !empty($lead->the_lead['full_name'])){
            }
        }

        $rtn[] = $row;
    }
    return $rtn;
}
```

Does any one has any suggestion about how to do it right and proper? thank you very much for any answer! Appreciate it!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is my working example, that How I am using this.

**My controller method for Datatable**

```
public function getData()
{

    $supplier  = Supplier::with('manufacturer')->select(['id','proprietor','qualified_person','manufacturer_id','license_no','nth_registration_no','phone','mobile','email','address','status']);


    return Datatables::of($supplier)
            ->editColumn('status', function($supplier){
             return (($supplier->status == 1)?"Active":"Deactive");
            })
            ->editColumn('phone', function($supplier){
             return "Phone#: ".$supplier->phone." <br /> Mobile#: ".$supplier->mobile;
            })
            ->editColumn('manufacturer_id', function($supplier){
             //return $supplier->manufacturer->name;
                if($supplier->manufacturer_id != 0){
                    return $supplier->manufacturer->name;
                }else{
                    return 'Not selected!';
                }

            })
            ->addColumn('actions', '
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="{!!route("supplier-edit",["id"=>$id ])!!}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                    <a href="{!!route("ajax-delete",["type"=>"supplier","id"=>$id ])!!}" data-target="#ajax_delete" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                ')
            ->remove_column('mobile')
            ->make(true);        

}
```

**my View structure**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content" id="supplier">
    <thead class="flip-content">
        <tr>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Qualified Person</th>
            <th>Proprietor</th>
            <th>License#</th>
            <th>Reg#</th>
            <th>Contact#</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Datatable JS for server side processing**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oTable;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        oTable = $('#supplier').DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{!!route('supplier-data')!!}",
            "columns": [
                {data: 'manufacturer_id',              name: 'manufacturer_id'},
                {data: 'qualified_person',              name: 'qualified_person'},
                {data: 'proprietor',              name: 'proprietor'},
                {data: 'license_no',              name: 'license_no'},
                {data: 'nth_registration_no',              name: 'nth_registration_no'},
                {data: 'phone',             name: 'phone'},
                {data: 'email',             name: 'email'},
                //{data: 'mobile',            name: 'mobile'},
                {data: 'address',           name: 'address'},
                {data: 'status',            name: 'status'},
                {data: 'actions',           name: 'actions'},
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

**here is the example of picking items from multiple laravel relationship.**

```
public function getData()
{

    $medicine  = Medicine::with(['manufacturer','doseageForm','measureUnit','supplier'])
                ->select(['id','product_name','generic_name','product_class','manufacturer_id', 
                          'doseage_form_id','measure_unit_id','strenght','status']);

    return Datatables::of($medicine)
            ->editColumn('status', function($medicine){
                return (($medicine->status == 1)?"Active":"Deactive");
            })
            ->editColumn('manufacturer_id', function($medicine){

                $manufacturer_name   =   $medicine->manufacturer->name;
                return $manufacturer_name;
            })
            ->editColumn('product_name', function($medicine){
                return 
                    $medicine->product_name.", ".
                        $medicine->doseageForm->name.", ".
                        $medicine->strenght.$medicine->measureUnit->name;
            })
            ->addColumn('supplier',function($medicine){

                if($medicine->supplier->count() > 0){
                    return $medicine->supplier->first()->qualified_person;
                }else{
                    return '---';
                }


            })
            ->addColumn('actions', function($medicine){

                $edit_route =   route('medicine-edit',['id'=>$medicine->id ]);
                $del_route  =   route("ajax-delete",["type"=>"medicine","id"=>$medicine->id ]);

                $status     =   (($medicine->status == 1)?
                                    '<a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>'
                                    :
                                    '<a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></a>'
                                );

                $html       =   '<div class="btn-group">
                                    '.$status.'
                                    <a href="'.$edit_route.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" alt="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                    <a href="'.$del_route.'" data-target="#ajax_delete" alt="delete" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>';

                return $html;
            })
            ->make(true);        

}
```