# Condition on Datatables and Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have a laravel project, what I want to do is make a condition if the user is admin, there will show the add and edit button, and if not the button won't appear.

this is my javascript on my view

```
@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var oTable = $('#tabel-stok').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                order: [[ 0 , "desc"]],
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ url("data-stok") }}'
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
                    {data: 'nama_produk', name: 'nama_produk'},
                    {data: 'harga_satuan', name: 'harga_satuan'},
                    {data: 'jumlah_stok', name: 'jumlah_stok'},
                    {
                        name: '',
                        data: null,
                        sortable: false,
                        searchable: false,
                        render: function (data) {
                            var actions = '';
                            actions += '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/tambah/:id"><span class="label label-primary">TAMBAH</span></a>';
                            actions += '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/edit/:id"><span class="label label-warning">EDIT</span></a>';
                            return actions.replace(/:id/g, data.id_produk);
                        }
                    }
                ],
            });
            console.log(oTable);
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

this is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    return view('transaksi-masuk.transaksi-masuk');
}

public function dataStok()
{
    $stoks = Produk::all();
    return Datatables::of($stoks)
        ->make(true);
}
```

Please help me, thank you

Comment: Show your database table structure,so it can help understanding, how you are differentiate users

Answer (score 0):

You are creating buttons at JavaScript end, It would be better and easier if you add columns/buttons from Controller end. Here is my example.

```
return Datatables::of($response)
      ->addColumn('action',function ($response){
         $html = null;

         if(USER IS ADMIN){ //your condition
           $html='<a href="'.route('response-edit-get',['id'=>$response->id ]).'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> |';
           $html.='<a href="#confirm-delete-'.$response->id.'" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>';
           return $html;
         }
       })
      ->make(true);
```

**and my javascript is like this**

```
$(function() {
    $('#responses-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        searching : true,
        "ordering": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "pageLength": 30,
        stateSave: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('completed-survey-data') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'results', name: 'results'},
            { data: 'action', name: 'action'}

        ],
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            tokenInputTriger();
        },
        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
                $(row).addClass( 'rowid_'+data.id );
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my detailed answer available, That will make more sense for your understanding.
[Detailed Answer for DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847872/laravel-and-yajrabox-datatables-server-side-proccessing?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set USER_IS_ADMIN veriable in blade page in script:

```
<script>
@if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->admin)
var USER_IS_ADMIN = true;
@else
var USER_IS_ADMIN = false;
@endif
</script>
```

And then just add if condition for edit button:

```
render: function (data) {
    var actions = '';
    actions += '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/tambah/:id"><span class="label label-primary">TAMBAH</span></a>';
    if(USER_IS_ADMIN ){
        actions += '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/edit/:id"><span class="label label-warning">EDIT</span></a>';
    }

    return actions.replace(/:id/g, data.id_produk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution. What you need to do is change the behavior of your script when appending the button to the `action` section. Here I use a simple checking whether current user is admin or not. You may change this `Auth::user()->isAdmin()` snippet to yours.

```
@section('script')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var oTable = $('#tabel-stok').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                order: [[ 0 , "desc"]],
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ url("data-stok") }}'
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
                    {data: 'nama_produk', name: 'nama_produk'},
                    {data: 'harga_satuan', name: 'harga_satuan'},
                    {data: 'jumlah_stok', name: 'jumlah_stok'},
                    {
                        name: '',
                        data: null,
                        sortable: false,
                        searchable: false,
                        render: function (data) {
                            var actions = '';

                            // USE YOUR OWN LOGIC TO DETERMINE IF CURRENT USER IS ADMIN OR NOT
                            @if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->isAdmin())
                            actions += '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/tambah/:id"><span class="label label-primary">TAMBAH</span></a>';
                            actions += '<a href="/transaksi-masuk/edit/:id"><span class="label label-warning">EDIT</span></a>';
                            @endif

                            return actions.replace(/:id/g, data.id_produk);
                        }
                    }
                ],
            });
            console.log(oTable);
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```